# sort a 2D list first by 1st column and then by 2nd column

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to find a nice way to sort a 2d list , first by the 1st value , and then by the 2nd value.

I think an example will be the best
If I have a list

```
[[1,4],
[2,7],
[10,1],
[1,2],
[10,6]
[2,1]]
```

I want that is will be sorted like this

```
[[1,2],
[1,4],
[2,1],
[2,7],
[10,1],
[10,6]]
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
l=[[1,4],
[2,7],
[10,1],
[1,2],
[10,6],
[2,1]]
print(sorted(l,key=lambda x: (x[0],x[1]))) # use lambda to sort by "x[0]"-> first element of the sublists or x[1] -> second element, if its a tie
[[1, 2], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 7], [10, 1], [10, 6]]
```

Or simply `sorted(l)` of `l.sort()` as your elements sort naturally.

A better example would be to sort by the second value only:

```
print(sorted(l,key=lambda x: (x[1])))
[[10, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2], [1, 4], [10, 6], [2, 7]]
```